# Ubuntu 14.04 PHPMyAdmin can't find mcrypt extension

Tags: apache2, 14.04, phpmyadmin

I've tried suggestions for solving this dealing with 13.10, but they don't seem to work. Hard refresh of the page doesn't remove the error. PHPMyAdmin has a box at the bottom indicating that the mcrypt extension is missing, even though it is installed for php.

How do I fix this?

Comment: **extension=mcrypt.so** did the trick for me ! Thanks !

Comment: `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` <br/>
That is ok to me.

Comment: Ran into this problem earlier today, so I tried the recommended solution but was still seeing the error, so I decided to reboot and, wouldn't you know it, voila.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix that worked for me was relatively simple:

The solution: add the following line to the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file:

`extension=mcrypt.so`

This line causes the mcrypt extension to be loaded automatically when the server restarts. I don't know why Arda's instructions didn't accomplish the same thing in my case, but I think it might have something to do with upgrading from earlier versions of Linux.

Answer (score 8):

[This is a reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/1240590). I had the same issue, found the answer [here on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184310&p=12832240#post12832240), so all credits goes to [SeijiSensei](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=698195):.

1) The mcrypt.ini file in `/etc/php5/conf.d` needs to be copied or symlinked to `/etc/php5/mods-available`:

```
cd /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo ln -s ../conf.d/mcrypt.ini .
```

2) Activate the module with `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`.

3) Restart your web server: If using Apache, it's like this: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Then log into the PMA, the issue will be fixed.

Comment: I followed these instructions exactly; the mcrypt extension message is still at the bottom of the page when I log into phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Adam have you restarted your web server?

Comment: I have; in fact, I restart my web server every time I reboot my computer, which is often, as it is a laptop I use for classes.

Comment: Weird, have you got any errors during these steps ? I'm using exactly this way, and I don't have the issue anymore.

Comment: No errors in any of the error logs for Apache. The solution I selected works, but I admit I don't know enough about what's happening to understand why your solution wouldn't work for me. It may just be that I have something of a non-standard setup.

Comment: Just for a heads-up, I've installed Apache and PHP using `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`.

Comment: That's also how I installed mine. Mine is also on a 64-bit machine (which probably makes no difference), fresh install. My guess is that both solutions work in different situations. It may also be the case that other means of fixing this problem interfered with your solution on my machine.

Comment: Same here. Maybe during the time I've tried the first solution worked, and later they changed something during updated and now the solution that you've accepted works, I really have no idea. I'll try to make a fresh installation soon, and if it changes I'll let you know.